# javascript regex single-line

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm trying to replace all @import strings in one single-string, e.g.

```
var str = 'buttons .reprint{height:56px;background-position:-47px -1496px;}@import "../common/buttons.css";@import "../screen/screen-1.css";@import "../screen/screen-2.css";@import "../screen/screen-3.css";@import "../screen/screen-5.css";@import "../screen/screen-6.css";@import "../screen/screen-7.css";@import "../screen/screen-quick-messages.css";@import "../screen/reset-password.css";#xml-data{display:none;}body{font-family:"Helvetica Neue",HelveticaNeue,Helvetica-Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;}ul{padding:0;}body,section{width:768px;}';
```

It works if I write:

```
console.log(str.match(/@import\ /g));
```

But how to specify, all @import declaration at all in single line, e.g. `@import "../screen/screen-1.css";`

```
console.log(str.match(/@import\ .+;/g));
```

doesn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to replace the imports with?

Comment: As for the reason why your `.+` "didn't work", the type of "didn't work" I can think of is that it matched too much, because + is greedy, meaning it would go to the last semicolon it found. Adding `?` to a quantifier makes it becomes non-greedy - so `/@import\ .+?;/g` would work. But you could potentially have semicolons in the URL, so Tim's answer is obviously much better.  Just wanted to explain what was wrong in case it helps another time. But do be as specific as you can always, it avoids errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like an `@import` always has this format:

> @import (whitespace) (quote) (one or more non-quote characters) (quote) (semicolon)

If that's true, then let's build the regex accordingly:

```
 /@import\s*"[^"]+";/
```

This should match each `@import` statement separately.

Comment: I think that solution given by somethingkindawierd is more general and deserves to be marked as answer.

Comment: @Roboblob: That may be (although Alex appears to disagree), but why is that a reason to downvote my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's already answered, but I just want to offer a simpler version of the pattern above.

I needed this regex for removing @import statements from css files I merged together.

It matches the pattern:

```
@import (anything NOT a semicolon) (semicolon)
```

Works great. Here's an example of how I use it:

```
// $mergedStyles set earlier in script...

// matches the pattern 
// ["@import"]+[anything NOT a semicolon]+semicolon
// e.g.: "@import url("stuff");
$pattern = '/@import[^;]*;/';
$mergedStyles = preg_replace($pattern, '', $mergedStyles);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, i like this solution better since its more general and catches more variations of @import.